# How to implement bottom navigation drawer in flutter in a newly created project?

Tags: flutter

I wish to make an application that has bottom navigation view. How do I implement this in flutter? I saw some youtube video but nothing is working out.

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use BottomNavigationBar [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) is the documentation:

You can implement BottomNavigation Like this.

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new _BottomBarState();
  }
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;
//here in the initstate we assign the tabcontroller and give it a length and vsyc for animation.
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = new TabController(initialIndex: 1,length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

//dispose method for good practice.
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    tabController.dispose();
  }

//our build widget of state class.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('bottomNavigation'),
        ),

        bottomNavigationBar: new Material(

          child: new TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              new Tab(
                child: new Icon(Icons.star),
              ),
              new Tab(
                child: new Icon(Icons.favorite),
              ),
              new Tab(
                child: new Icon(Icons.headset),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )); //scaffold
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For widgets like bottom navigation drawer and more have look at this repo ..

**Demo app for the material design widgets and other features provided by Flutter.**
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery